# Does boost::iostreams::filtering_istream allow seeks?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to write a Boost iostreams filter that supports seeking.  My filter seems to work OK (well, it compiles), but I got a nasty surprise when it tried to seek on the underlying file and got a "no random access" exception.

Sure enough, it doesn't seem to work in a test case (Ubuntu 14.04; boost 1.54):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>

namespace io = boost::iostreams;

main()
{
    std::ifstream input_file("hi");
    io::filtering_istream instream;

    instream.push(input_file);

    input_file.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
    instream.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);

    // this works                                                                                                                  
    input_file.seekg(0);

    // this doesn't                                                                                                                
    instream.seekg(0);
}
```

`touch hi` and compile with `g++ -o test_seek test_seek.cc`

Any ideas how to seek on a `filtering_istream` with an underlying seekable file?

Comment: Can you try io::filtering_stream<io::input_seekable>?

Comment: @lrm29 Yes, that did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

To support seeking is need to define a capability of an underlying device by the tag **input_seekable**. Then all filters and device must support seeking otherwise the code cannot be compiled. In the following example, YourFilter must be seekable and defined tag **seekable_filter_tag** to compile.

```
namespace io = boost::iostreams;    
io::filtering_stream<io::input_seekable> input(YourFilter() | boost::ref(input_file));
```